# Android "No view found for id for fragment"

Tags: android, fragment, illegalargumentexception

Okay. I am stuck and having a headache... I am not sure how to access the other layout's view, since inflating does not work.
Here are my codes.

**WriteRouteActivity.java**

```
public class WriteRouteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar tb;
    private TextView txt_toolbar_title;
    private Button btnSearchPlaces;
    private LinearLayout parentLayout, placesCoverLayout;
    private View popupView;
    private ImageView imgShowPlaces;
    private boolean isKeyBoardVisible;
    private int keyboardHeight;
    private EditText edtSearchPlaces;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;

    //popupView
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    //prework
    private int minusVal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_route);
        initView();

    }

    private void initView() {
        //for activity and native back button

        tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        txt_toolbar_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_toolbar);

        parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_parent);
        placesCoverLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_for_places);
        imgShowPlaces = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_show_places);
        edtSearchPlaces =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_search_place);
        btnSearchPlaces = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search_place);

        popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.places_popup, null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

        doWorkForLayotus();
    }

    private void doWorkForLayotus(){
        final float popUpheight = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.keyboard_height);
        changeKeyboardHeight((int) popUpheight);
        enablePopUpView();
        setTabLayout();
        checkKeyboardHeight(parentLayout);
        enableFooterView();
    }

    public void setCurrentTabFragment(int position) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        String tag="";
        Fragment fr = null;
        Class frClass = null;
        FragmentManager frManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tag = "first";
                //hide
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")).commit();
                }

                //show
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().show(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")).commit();
                }else{  //add
                    try {
                        frManager.beginTransaction().add(frameLayout.getId(), ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("why", e.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                tag = "second";
                //hide
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")).commit();
                }

                //show
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().show(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")).commit();
                }else{  //add
                frManager.beginTransaction().add(frameLayout.getId(), ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                tag = "third";
                //hide
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")).commit();
                }

                //show
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().show(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")).commit();
                }else{  //add
                    frManager.beginTransaction().add(frameLayout.getId(), ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                tag = "fourth";
                //hide
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("first")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("second")).commit();
                }
                if(frManager.findFramentByTag("third")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().hide(frManager.findFragmentByTag("third")).commit();
                }

                //show
                if(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")!=null){
                    frManager.beginTransaction().show(frManager.findFragmentByTag("fourth")).commit();
                }else{  //add
                    frManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout, ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();
                }
                break;
        }
        //frManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fr, tag).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
    }

    private void setTabLayout(){
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                try {
                    setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void enablePopUpView() {

        // Creating a pop window for emoticons keyboard
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (int) keyboardHeight, false);

        popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                placesCoverLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    int previousHeightDiffrence = 0;
    private void checkKeyboardHeight(final View parentLayout) {

        parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        parentLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                        int screenHeight = parentLayout.getRootView()
                                .getHeight();
                        minusVal=screenHeight-r.bottom;
                        int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom+(minusVal));

                        if (previousHeightDiffrence - heightDifference > 50) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }

                        previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;
                        if (heightDifference > 100) {

                            isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                            changeKeyboardHeight(heightDifference);

                        } else {

                            isKeyBoardVisible = false;

                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    private void changeKeyboardHeight(int height) {

        if (height > 100) {
            keyboardHeight = height;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyboardHeight);
            placesCoverLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

    }

    private void enableFooterView() {
        edtSearchPlaces.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        btnSearchPlaces.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(WriteRouteActivity.this);
                if(!popupWindow.isShowing()){
                    popupWindow.setHeight((int) (keyboardHeight));

                    if (isKeyBoardVisible) {
                        placesCoverLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                    } else {
                        placesCoverLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
                    popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentLayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

                    try {
                        setCurrentTabFragment(0);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    //popupWindow.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                        Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(popupWindow.isShowing()){
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_write_wroute.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/nav_toolbar" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        layout="@layout/footer_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_for_places"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/keyboard_height"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment_Zasin**

```
public class Fragment_zasin  extends Fragment {
    public Fragment_zasin newInstance() {
        Fragment_zasin fr = new Fragment_zasin();
        return fr;
    }

    public Fragment_zasin() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zasin, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**places_popup.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/tab_pin_selector"
            android:text="11">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabItem>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/tab_mainroute_selector"
            android:text="22" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/tab_talk_selector"
            android:text="33" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/tab_my_selector"
            android:text="44" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT Message**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: suacuration.itgotravel, PID: 20131
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f100173 for fragment Fragment_zasin{d4ac39c #0 id=0x7f100173 first}

Can somebody help this?

Comment: please post your XML layout, fragment_zasin

Comment: @curiousMind um there is nothing inside fragment_zasin.xml. just a textview with android:text="hello"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i found an answer.
The problem was that fragment cannot be a child of a 'Dialog'.
Since i used popup dialog, it was unable to put fragments inside the dialog.

i solved by inflating views rather than using fragments in tablayout.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because the fragment manager could not find the view on which it has to inflate the fragment.

The fragment transaction is linked to the activity so this error occurs as the frame layout is not a part of that main activity's xml.so it cant find where to add the fragment.fragment has to be added inside the activity.

what you have to do is provide the id of a view in your main activity.
for e.g your main view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainView"//like this
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/nav_toolbar" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<include
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    layout="@layout/footer_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_for_places"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/keyboard_height"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The view where you are trying to inflate the fragemnt must be inside activity.
Now when you try

```
frManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainView, ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();
```

the fragment will be loaded on this view of your activity.

Comment: I already tried that, and same error happens and the logcat's error message is the same.

Comment: When i checked through Logcat, those two id's are the same, and they are all not NULL. However since the frame_layout is from places_popup.xml, i guess there should be a method for the "frame_layout" to be accessed from that activity. but i do not know how to do that..

Comment: It will.you have to start transaction for a layout inside the main layout.

Comment: i don't understand. what does it mean  "start transaction for a layout inside the main layout"??

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are trying to show a `Fragment` on a `View` which is not defined in your layout which you have defined in your `onCreate()` while `setContentView(layoutId)`

In your case you are inflating fragments in `WriteRouteActivity` where layout defined is `activity_write_route` and fragments are added on `FrameLayout` which is defined in `places_popup.xml` so define your `framelayout` in a view layout of Activity.

Small Description :

```
--------code------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
-------layout define for activity-------
setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_route);
}
```

now where you are adding fragment on a `FrameLayout(view)`

```
frManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout, ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();
```

here `R.id.frame_layout` should be define in your layout `activity_write_route`.

Comment: can you explain more? i don't get this part "framelayout in a content view of Activity"

Comment: no any alternatives? why inflating frame layout from a view does not work? very curious

Answer (score 0):

There could be other errors but what is this?

```
tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_toolbar);
```

This is not a toolbar:

```
<include layout="@layout/nav_toolbar" />
```

Can we see inside this nav_toolbar layout?

Also, where is this: "R.layout.fragment_zasin". It's complaining about a Fragment so it would be worthwhile seeing if this is ok.

Anyway, as a general troubleshooting strategy, try commenting out all those lines in the initView() method and just add them in one at a time until it fails. Or maybe if you scroll down in the error logs further it will give you a hyperlink to the line that's causing it to fail.

Why do you have "frameLayout.getId()" on one line but "R.id.frame_layout" on another? Try to use the latter for all of the lines and see if that's it.

Comment: he is including toolbar using include tag.

Comment: yeah that's right. ignore that toolbar. i just copied my code from Android Studio. that layout works well...

Comment: unfortunately, that hyperlink does not appear. when i tried that strategy, i found out that runtime error occurs when this "frManager.beginTransaction().add(frameLayout.getId(), ((Fragment) Fragment_zasin.class.newInstance()), tag).commit();" needs to run and the compiler(?) cannot find the view "framelayout.getid()" either "R.id.frame_layout"

Comment: Why do you have "frameLayout.getId()" on one line but "R.id.frame_layout" on another? Try to use the latter for all of the lines and see if that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I was extending the wrong type of activity, extended AppCompact solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when starting new fragment from fragment, using `ChildFragmentManager`, and giving id of container from activity, in transaction replace method.
It happens that `FragmentManager` has access to activity containers, but `ChildFragmentManager` has access to fragment containers.
The solution was to use `FragmentManager` class instead of `ChildFragmentManager`.

Answer (score -3):

You got this error because **your view found for id 0x7f100173 into fragment Fragment_zasin** so only solution is that:

1) check all id present to that particular layout.

2) if all id is present to that particular layout and still you facing same issue do one thing change name of id don't refactor change name and access this changed id name in your fragment or activity.